# How to update 2D array with another 2D array matching on an id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two lists and would like to update one with the other on a matching index.

```
let cart = [{
  header: some_data,
  items: [{
    id: 7,
    properties: some_props_7,
    time: 12345
  }, {
    id: 19,
    properties: some_props_19,
    time: 13344
  }, {
    id: 24,
    properties: some_props_24,
    time: 14342
  }]
}, etc.];

let newData = [{
  header: some_data,
  items: [{
    id: 19,
    properties: some_new_props_19,
    time: 17744
  }, {
    id: 24,
    properties: some_new_props_24,
    time: 18342
  }]
}, etc.];
```

I am iterating over the cart, but am not coming up with an efficient way to update. I think I need another for loop in the "update cart" section, but that seems sub-optimal to me.

`k` is a list of indices

```
let i = 0, j = 0, l = cart.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  let m = cart[i]['items'].length;
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    // update cart index with associated newData matching on id
  }
}
```

How do I update the header and items data in the cart from a dynamic newData list?

Answer (score 1):

Filter out overlaps and concatenate with new items:

```js
let cart = {
 header: 'some_data',
 items: [{
  id: 7,
  properties: 'some_props_7',
  time: 12345
 }, {
  id: 19,
  properties: 'some_props_19',
  time: 13344
 }, {
  id: 24,
  properties: 'some_props_24',
  time: 14342
 }]
};

let newData = {
 header: 'some_data',
 items: [{
  id: 19,
  properties: 'some_new_props_19',
  time: 17744
 }, {
  id: 24,
  properties: 'some_new_props_24',
  time: 18342
 }]
};
//TEST
console.log(
 cart.items.filter(item => !newData.items.map(i => i.id).includes(item.id)).concat(newData.items)
);
```

**Updated in response to comments**

It now maps properly over lists.

```js
var cart = [{
  header: 'some_data',
  items: [{
    id: 7,
    properties: 'some_props_7',
    time: 12345
  }, {
    id: 19,
    properties: 'some_props_19',
    time: 13344
  }, {
    id: 24,
    properties: 'some_props_24',
    time: 14342
  }]
}];
var newData = [{
  header: 'some_data',
  items: [{
    id: 19,
    properties: 'some_new_props_19',
    time: 17744
  }, {
    id: 24,
    properties: 'some_new_props_24',
    time: 18342
  }]
}];
//TEST
cart = cart
  //Modify existing data elements
  .map(function(car) {
    newData.forEach(function(data) {
      if (data.header === car.header) {
        car.items = car.items.filter(function(item) {
          return !data.items.map(function(i) {
            return i.id;
          }).includes(item.id);
        }).concat(data.items);
      }
    });
    return car;
  })
  //Add new data elements
  .concat(newData.filter(function(data) {
    return !cart.some(function(car) {
      return car.header === data.header;
    });
  }));
console.log(cart);
```

Comment: The cart data and newData are arrays, so must also be traversed... i.e., could have many headers with many items for each header.

Comment: Then use a recursive forEach


recursiveFunction = function(ObjectToRecurse) {

            ObjectToRecurse.forEach(index => {
                if (index) {
                   // add to your new object
                } else {
                    return this.recursiveFunction(account.childElements)
                }
            }, this)
}